# Resharper breaking Visual Studio 2019 functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019, resharper

I have been using Visual Studio 2019 with Resharper. After last Visual Studio update I had to also reinstall Resharper. However, now VS functionality in some files doesn't work(Yes, VS functionality in some files working correctly, but in others not).

Here is the list of problems I noticed:

1. Variable types not showing, instead it shows blank space:[image]
2. Search for file not working
3. Scroll bar is not working, indicator just freezes
4. Line numbers are also lagging, it stays static while scrolling the page
5. Sometimes, shortcut commands not work for the file

Info:

- Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition Version 16.10.3
- JetBrains Resharper 2021.1.2 built on 2021-04-20
- Project environment: .NET Framework 4.6.1

I tried to fix/reinstall Visual Studio and Resharper, not fixed the problem.
Visual Studio works fine If I disable Resharper

Comment: I had the same issues but after an update to version 2021.1.3 of reshaper the problems disappeared

Comment: Really would be best to post to JB's https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Issue+Tracker

Comment: I have the same setup as you (NET 4.8 project) but I don't have the problems you mention. Only the reference counter disappeared after the last VS update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution for me was updating Resharper to 2021.1.3 (*Connor Stoop* mentioned in comments)

Answer (score 1):

[2021.1.5 version is released](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/#section=offline-installer) which fixes the problem.

Comment: I have same issue with Resharper 2021.2.2 and VS2019

Answer (score 1):

This is also happening to me with Visual Studio 2019 16.10.3 and ReShaper Ultimate 2021.1.4, I'm seeing the problem

1. While scrolling the current edited file, the line number and breakpoint indicators do not scroll with the text.
2. Copying and Pasting a block of code or even single line, copies it 5-6 times, messing up the code.

Workarounds are:

1. simply to close and re-open the file 1-2 times.
2. to suspend ReSharper done in Tools->Options->Reshaper and hit suspend.